# Vector Keeps over printing output

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS 2
pthread_mutex_t mutexChild;
pthread_cond_t condChild;

vector<int> vect;

void openfile(ifstream&, string);

void* childthread(void *args)
{
    
    ifstream inFile;
    openfile(inFile, "Fruits.txt");
    
    string line;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexChild);
    int countt = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int total = 0;
    
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        
        getline(inFile, line);
        
        countt = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
            if ((line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z')
                    || (line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z'))
            {
                
                countt++;
            }
        
        lines++;
        vect.push_back(countt);
    }
    
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexChild);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* parentthread(void *args)
{
    
    ifstream inFile;
    openfile(inFile, "Fruits.txt");
    string line;
    
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexChild);
    
    int lines = 0;
    int total = 0;
    
    int countt = 0;
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        
        getline(inFile, line);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
            cout << vect[i] << endl;
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    pthread_t threads;
    int thrd1;
    //int i;
    int thrd2;
    
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexChild, NULL);
    
    thrd1 = pthread_create(&threads, NULL, childthread, NULL);
    
    if (thrd1)
    {
        cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << thrd1 << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    pthread_t threads2;
    
    thrd2 = pthread_create(&threads2, NULL, parentthread, NULL);
    
    if (thrd2)
    {
        cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << thrd2 << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    
// pthread_join(threads,NULL);
// pthread_join(threads2, NULL);
//threads.join();
///threads2.join();
    
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexChild);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&condChild);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void openfile(ifstream &inFile, string fname)
{
    
    inFile.open(fname);
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        
        // cout << "Successfully opened File" << endl;
    }
}
```

My child threads keeps printing the output 8 times when I only need it to print once. There are 8 lines in my txt file so im guessing thats why its printing the output 8 times. Can anyone tell me why it's doing and how I change it. I also know there is an easier why to do this task but I am required to exchange data using posix threads.
Its printing like this
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
8 times
when I just need
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

Comment: Recommendation: change `while (!inFile.eof()) { getline(inFile, line);` to `while (getline(inFile, line)) {`. [Rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons);

Comment: Side note: instead of platform specific `pthread.h` library, you should consider the C++11 standard `<thread>` header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        
        getline(inFile, line);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
            cout << vect[i] << endl;
    }
```

prints out the contents of the `vector` built in the child thread once for every line in the file (sort of. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)). This is not what you want. There doesn't seem to be any need to read the file here. The child thread already read the file and did all the `vector` assembly work.

All you should need to solve the immediate problem, repeated printing of the data, is

```cpp
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
        cout << vect[i] << endl;
```

Comment: when I try to take it out the while loop it won't print at all.

Comment: Make absolutely certain that parent thread isn't grabbing the mutex and completing before the child thread gets a chance to start nd populate the `vector`. I'd use a condition variable for this job rather than just a mutex.